# Transfer data between android device over wifi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I want to send data (for an example it contains the information: name,address) from my app to another hotspot enabled android device using the same app and display the information in it. So, how do I transfer? If it is not possible please tell me if there any possible way to transfer data via WiFi. Since I am new, procedure with code help me a lot.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345155/android-receive-and-send-data-through-wifi-connection-to-hardware

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) is what you need. P2P communication can only by performed by devices that run android 4.0 and up.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please consider posting essential elements of answer here. Link only answers can go dead over a period of time.