# Android. How to fetch a string from Wifi?

Tags: android, string, wifi, fetch

I have an Arduino WiFi server connected to a router, and I want to send a string to an Android application connected to the same network. How can I get that string?

More specific. I want to enable airplane mode while the app receive that string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from Arduino WiFi server you have to send string to android that connected with same network.

Comment: first your android app send CMD to broadcast IP and port of same network. and then Arduino server will listen on same port and give response of that CMD.

Comment: Do you have a code example? I've read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345155/android-receive-and-send-data-through-wifi-connection-to-hardware
But I don't know if that's what I need.

Comment: visit http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Comment: Your wifi will have to be on. You can just use TCP sockets to communicate between the two.

Comment: 'I want to send a string to an Android application connected to the same network.'. Applications are not connected to networks. Devices or OS' are. Applications are connected to other applications on that network. They can use sockets for that. So you want to send a string? Can you rephrase your problem?